# What happens when the second derivative of a multivariate function is defined in the "naive" way?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, normed-spaces

Let $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$ be a differentiable function. The derivative of $f$ at $x$ is the unique linear map $f'(x):\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$ such that
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)-f'(x)h}{\lVert h\rVert}=0 \, .
$$
As far as I can tell, this definition makes sense in the more general context of a function between two normed spaces over $\mathbb R$, although we need the extra requirement that $f'(x)$ is a bounded linear operator.

If we regard $f'$ as a function from $\mathbb R^n$ to $L(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R^m)$, where $L(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R^m)$ is equipped with the supremum norm, say, is there any geometric or analytical significance of the "second derivative" $f''$ at $x$ satisfying
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f'(x+h)-f'(x)-f''(x)h}{\lVert h\rVert}=0 \, ?
$$
Does this definition even make sense? In the above equation, the idea is that we are taking the limit of a function from $\mathbb R^n$ to $L(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R^m)$; this function converges to the zero function $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$ in the supremum norm.

If the "second derivative" exists at every point, then it seems like $f''$ may be regarded as a function $\mathbb R^n\to L(\mathbb R^n,L(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R^m))$, I *think*.

Comment: Yes the definition makes sense. This is well explained in many texts (Loomis Sternberg, or some of the French books, like Dieudonne, Henri Cartan etc), and I personally have written many answers on this site regarding this (and related topics like Taylor’s theorem in the Banach space setting). Note that you can consider $f’’(x)$ as a bilinear-map (by basic linear algebra), and the key theorem is this is actually symmetric (this implies symmetry of mixed partials).

Comment: @peek-a-boo: Apologies for the late reply. I'm a little unsure about your comment saying that you can consider $f''(x)$ as a bilinear map. Suppose $f:V\to W$ is a map between normed spaces. Then, $f''$ is a map from $V$ to $\operatorname{Hom}(V,\operatorname{Hom}(V,W))$, and so for each $x\in V$, $f''(x)$ is a linear map from $V$ to $\operatorname{Hom}(V,W)$. Via currying, we can identify $f''(x)$ with the map $\widetilde{f''}(x):V\times V\to W$ such that $f''(x)(v_1)(v_2)=\widetilde{f''}(x)(v_1,v_2)$. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that’s what I mean, and you can prove that this map is bilinear and symmetric.

Comment: @peek-a-boo: Thank you. Proving equality of mixed partials via this method seems very neat. Is this done in the books you referenced, e.g. Loomis and Sternberg?

Comment: Yes it’s proven in all the texts; the proof relies on the mean-value inequality.